# How can we achieve Earthquake Simulation in Unity - Simulation of P and S Waves

Tags: unity, mesh, dynamic-mesh

> I Cannot use Water waves as P and S Waves are different than water waves. I tried to use it but not satisfied with the result.

I am trying to simulate how Earthquake takes place in real time which you cannot simulate in the real world. Here is the reference link to understand the basics of [Earthquake](http://www.geo.mtu.edu/UPSeis/waves.html) and to understand better here is the better-simulated [Example](http://ds.iris.edu/seismon/swaves/). I wanted to Simulate P and S Waves. My first attempt will be simulating with mesh instead of showing lines, I don't know how to compress mesh (P Waves) but I found out a good example to simulate wave like effect (S Waves).

The solution I am looking forward to is :

1. Any idea of how I can compress - decompress mesh in Unity (P Waves).
2. wave like effect (S waves), I have an example but it moves only Plane, in my case, i want to do more like a deformation of mesh, so it gives me an real effect like S Waves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to do this you will have to write some code to [modify the mesh programmatically](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mesh.html). This is how you read the vertices of a mesh from a C# script:

```
Mesh mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
Vector3[] vertices = mesh.vertices;
```

And this is how you write them back:

```
mesh.vertices = vertices;
mesh.RecalculateBounds();
mesh.RecalculateNormals();
mesh.RecalculateTangents();
```

(Note that depending on the shader your mesh is using, recalculating the normals and/or tangents might not actually be needed. If you comment it out and the light on the mesh still looks correct, you can leave it out).

Now about the complicated part: Calculating the deformation of your mesh. I think the best way to do this would be to create a copy of the original vertex array in the Start method. Your Update method should now take that original array and run each vertex through a function which takes the vertex and a timecode as input and then returns a new vertex which says where that vertex should be at that timecode.

I am not a seismologist, so I can't tell you how this function would look exactly for physically correct S-waves or P-waves. So here is an example which applies a simple sine wave to the z-axis of the mesh which travels in x direction. You should be able to edit the wave functions to do what you want it to do:

```
private Vector3[] originalVertices;
private Mesh mesh;

void Start() {
    mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
    originalVertices = mesh.vertices;
}


void Update() { 

    Vector3[] newVertices = new Vector3[originalVertices.Length];

    for(int i = 0; i < originalVertices.Length; i++) {
        newVertices[i] = WaveFunction(originalVertices[i], Time.time);
    }
    
    mesh.vertices = newVertices;
    mesh.RecalculateBounds();
    mesh.RecalculateNormals();
    mesh.RecalculateTangents();
}

private Vector3 WaveFunction(Vector3 origin, float timeCode) {
     // sine wave with an amplitude of 1 unit and a period of 2π units, 
     // traveling with a speed of 1 unit per second.
     // Change this to your own wave function.
     return new Vector3 (
          origin.x,
          origin.y,
          origin.z + Mathf.Sin(origin.x + timeCode)
     );
}
```

My testing mesh in Blender:
[image: mesh]

The result in Unity (quite hypnotic):
[image: wave]

Comment: your code really helps me and takes me one step further to the result I wanted. I need one further help from you. check out P wave and Rayleigh wave in the [link](http://www.geo.mtu.edu/UPSeis/waves.html). I wanted to do the same in Mesh, but I have no idea how to make the upper part of mesh in moving and lower part of the same mesh still.

Comment: @KartikShah As I wrote: We are game developers, not a seismologists. If you want to know more about the math which can be used to describe different kinds of seismic waves, you should ask on [Earth Science Stack Exchange](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/seismology)

Comment: I want your help in mesh editing, that link have the GIF of how mesh movement is done in the wave although thanks for the help.